# Tutorial for basic numerical methods for PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I'm afraid this is probably not going to be a "good" question, but I'd like to use *Mathematica* to learn about basic numerical schemes for solving pdes. For example, I'd like to compute the solution of a 2D heat equation initial value problem using finite differences and Euler timestepping, and then look at how big errors are or stability (not interested in using `NDSolve` directly).

My question is, are there any resources that already do this the "right" way? I'm just getting acquainted with *Mathematica* and don't know the language well, but I do know I want to use packed arrays and avoid loops. There's lots of language-agnostic references for the numerical methods themselves, but I can't find good clean examples of *Mathematica* implementations of these methods.

Edit:

One of the books recommended in the answers suggest doing stuff like (1d heat equation IVP):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
gridX = 10; (* num interior points *)
dx = 1./gridX;
dt = .005; (*cfl: dt/dx^2 <= .5 *)

T[i_, j_] := T[i, j] = T[i, j - 1] + 
                  (dt/dx^2) (T[i + 1, j - 1] - 2 T[i, j - 1] + T[i - 1, j - 1]);

T[i_, 0] := 1. (* initial value *)

T[0,         j_] := 0.; (* boundaries *)
T[gridX + 1, j_] := 0.; 

TFinal[t_] := Table[T[i, IntegerPart[t/ dt]], {i, 1, gridX}];
ListLinePlot[TFinal[1]]
```

But I suspect that it's not the best way, because as soon as I crank up the grid size and shrink down the time step, I get a recursion limit error. The code above is storing the solution at all time steps, which I definitely don't want. I'm sure there are clean, non-recursive sample implementations of this method out there, just can't seem to find.

Comment: trott's books are very good:[Trott](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematica-GuideBook-Numerics-Michael-Trott/dp/0387950117/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1365568508&sr=8-1&keywords=trott+numeric)

Comment: a book is not a resource? in any case, i'm just interested in seeing some code, don't care if it's in a book, a website, or a stone tablet. what i'm definitely not interested in are comments like yours. just move along.

Answer (score 2):

This book should be helpful, I think it's what you're looking for.

[Numerical and Analytical Methods for Scientists and Engineers, Using Mathematica](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471266108)

Also [The Mathematica GuideBook for Numerics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950117)